# Egg and chicken problem when auto generate default makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Can't understand next moment in the official GMU Make documentation ([3.5 How Makefiles Are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles))

> If you do not specify any makefiles to be read with ‘-f’ or ‘--file’
> options, make will try the default makefile names; see What Name to
> Give Your Makefile. Unlike makefiles explicitly requested with ‘-f’ or
> ‘--file’ options, make is not certain that these makefiles should
> exist. However, if a default makefile does not exist but can be
> created by running make rules, you probably want the rules to be run
> so that the makefile can be used.

From which make rule default makefile can be created if we don't specify any makefile with -f and none of default makefiles are present ?
Can anybody give an example of that situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, the default makefile could be generated from the built-in rules that automatically check-out from version control system. The GNU make has built-in rules to checkout from RCS and SCCS, but nowadays no one is using those version control systems anymore.

One way to activate this feature was to create an empty directory, and setup a symlink to the RCS or SCCS repository. Once the symlink was setup, make will use the correct command (`co` for RCS, and `get` for SCCS) to checkout the latest version of the file.

Bottom line, IMHO, the feature is no longer relevant.

Comment: Thank you, as I understand docs for make is not a very good quality. Lack of examples, missing key points for complete understanding.

Comment: @DmitryPerfilyev If you find errors or inaccuracies you can help improving the documentation. This how free open source software works. Maintainers of free open source projects are usually quite happy to receive help.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, unfortunately that way it works only in your perfect world. In real word (if you ever tried to make changes in opensource) often nobody cares or  you must spend a lot of effort to apply your changes. see http://gnu-make.2324884.n4.nabble.com/notes-about-make-docs-p-3-5-td20544.html

Comment: @DmitryPerfilyev As I was a bit surprised I had a look at the discussion you linked and, honestly, I think the GNU make maintainers spent a lot of time and effort explaining you why the example you asked to be added in the documentation was too obscure and kind of _corner case_. They also spent a lot of time and effort trying to explain where the problems you had come from. And, finally, they agreed that the paragraph that puzzled you is now obsolete and should probably be reworked or completely removed in future versions.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - again, your dreams of perfect world don't have any in common with reality. A year has passed - there are no changes in this paragraph